# Are arduino passwords safe?

Tags: programming, hardware

Is an arduino password controlled lock safe or can the password be seen if they plug it in to a computer?

Comment: Most of the time you don't even need to connect a computer to it. Don't use a microcontroller for any sort of security unless you've spent at least a couple of months researching all the possible security issues.

Comment: When using no other tools than the regular Arduino IDE for programming the device, it is trivial to retrieve all its memory, including flash and EEPROM and with that the program, password or encryption keys. It is possible to lock the memory down, but the you can't reprogram the device any more and there are companies that specialize in reading AVR memory even when locked.

Comment: The trick here is to put the arduino behind the lock. So, unless they break the lock, which would make the password redundant? They have physical access to the arduino. And can use their debugging tools on it.
How were you thinking of inputting the password? By only giving them access to some I/O pins on the outside, I believe it becomes difficult if not impossible to retrieve the code/debug info. Be sure not to use any pins that double as programming/communication.
If someone has physical access, it's unlikely to make any protection. As they can read/re-program/bypass the arduino.

Comment: @jippie: You can reprogram a locked AVR: you just have to reset the lock bits first. This requires a chip erase though.

Comment: If "they" can get at the Arduino to "plug it into a computer" they can just activate whatever pin it is that unlocks the safe, so the question is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

There are no passwords inherent to Arduino. You can implement them any way you want, resulting in any safety level from zero safely to nearly uncrackable.

**Not so good**: store the passwords straight in EEPROM. No protection of your data means that there's always a way to read them.

**Quite safe**: hash the password before storing it, for instance through SHA-512. Even if you can read the list of hashed passwords, it's pretty hard (read: nearly impossible) to reverse the algorithm to get the password back. For that reason SHA functions are called one-way functions. When you enter a password you run it through the SHA algorithm and check the hash against the list of hashes in EEPROM.

Comment: But note that "quite safe" isn't "perfectly safe"; there are a number of security attacks that don't require you to ever access the memory of the device.

Comment: @Ignacio: Yes, that's why I used the word "quite" deliberately. For applications where security is prime (no pun intended) you wouldn't use just an Arduino anyway, but for instance an Arduino combined with [this Crypto-shield](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13183).